# Moneris Hosted Tokenization

Tags: payment-gateway

Is it possible to test Moneris hosted tokenization in local?

When I go to "Admin -> Hosted Tokenization", it asks for a source domain, but when I type a source domain as they ask, the only error message that I get is the digit "1" in red. Now I do not know if the error is due to a local domain (in my case i typed myapp.local) or something else. And even when I type some other domain that is really available on the Internet the same thing happens.

Is there anybody here that is familiar with this payment tool?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

As explained here, for development purposes you can just leave it empty! https://community.moneris.com/product-forums/f/5/t/1001

This will also allow you to do it from the local machine, without deployment to the host domain.

Comment: That link no longer works, it leads to a broken sign in page.

Comment: The link worked for me, but in case it goes down in the future, the answer from the Moneris rep was: "You can generate your profile ID without a source domain. Simply don’t put anything in the source domain field and press the “create profile” button. this also makes testing on your local workstation easier and is also necessary for some applications."

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue - a few things to note:

1. The source domain has to start with http:// (So it should really be called source URL, not domain..)
2. It sounds like you are on the classic portal. You should be using the new one - https://esqa.moneris.com/mpg/ (for the test environment) or https://www3.moneris.com/mpg/ (for production)

Answer (score 0):

I made a working example using the publicly available info.

As mentioned, you'll need info from mpg: you can add domains starting with `http://` or use the *Source URL authentication bypassed* one for `localhost`.

I used:

- `https://www3.moneris.com/HPPtoken/index.php` to get the token and
- `https://www3.moneris.com/gateway2/servlet/MpgRequest` to send the transaction to Vault...

Example config [here](https://github.com/Moneris/eCommerce-Canada-HostedSolutions/pull/1/files#diff-0dc4c6a58791631609b3e7ac3a4486a2).